# No saved view state

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have a view scoped bean that has a method call generateLicenseFile.

The method returns a String with this value

```
/licenseGenerated.xhtml?faces-redirect=true"
```

The JSF code for the page (agreementDetail.xhtml) looks like this

```
<h:commandButton value="Generate License File" action="#{agreement.generateLicenseFile}" />
```

When I click the button, I get an error

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: /agreementDetail.xhtmlNo saved view state could be found for the view identifier: /agreementDetail.xhtml
```

Any ideas?

--EDIT--

Just FYI, the "generateLicenseFile" method is not even executed, since I have logging that proves this.

Comment: Nevermind. I'm new to JSF and was doing a very dumb error. Sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No Saved  View** generally occurs when something goes wrong in the JSF Servlet life cycle.Maybe it's because of the View Scoped Bean.Try to change it to **Session Scoped** and make sure your managed bean entry is there in the **faces-config.xml**.

Another suggestion is in the generateLicenseFile method in the agreement bean return a String as "someStringName" and make sure you create a **navigation handler** in Faces Config with navigation rule and navigation case.